# Change gradle-tomcat-plugin root web application directory

Tags: tomcat, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-tomcat-plugin

I'm using the gradle-tomcat-plugin to run tomcat on a simple web application. What Im trying to do is to change the root web application directory from `src/main/webapp/` to `WebContent/`

```
tomcat {
    httpPort = 8080
    httpsPort = 8081
    enableSSL = false

    jasper {
        uriroot = file('WebContent')
    }
}
```

This is not working at all when I run `gradle tomcatRun` and it still maps to `src/main/webapp/`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the web application directory in Gradle is independent of the configuration properties exposed by the Tomcat plugin. The plugin that sets the default web app directory to `src/main/webapp` is the [War plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N1305C). To change this default directory assign a new value to the property `webAppDirName`, as shown in the following example:

```
webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
```